# Query data from DynamoDb based on date using graphql

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

All,

In my project i am saving the DateTime as number in milliseconds, Till now it is working fine, Now we got a requirement where we send a date and based on the date we need to query the DynamoDB and get the data, I have the datetime in milliseconds, How can i query it, Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

What about using [Resolver Mapping Template Utility Reference Util Time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html#time-helpers-in-util-time)? Probably you've already had queries working using milliseconds as args, right? You may pass two args in your query, i.e. `parsedDateTime` and `millisecondsDateTime`, both optional and in your resolver, you might do something like this on top of your query:

```
#if ( !$ctx.args.millisecondsDateTime && $ctx.args.parsedDateTime )
  #set( $ctx.args.millisecondsDateTime = $util.time.parseISO8601ToEpochMilliSeconds($ctx.args.parsedDateTime) )
#end
```

This way you keep your original query and just adapt your args to it.